# Removing a row with stylus on Firefox

Tags: css, stylus

I'm visiting a page with a table listing a few rows. Since there is no option I'd like to hide the whole `<tr>` that got a `label = Hide`. I've spend a couple of hours but can't figure out how to achieve this with Stylus.

Example of the html on the page:

```
<tr id="xxx" class="basic-m" title="Y and X" label="Hide">
   <td> Various text here </td>
</tr>
```

I'm not even sure if I should post this here, but can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`[attribute="value"]` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
tr[label="Hide"]
```

This can be seen in the following:

```css
tr[label="Hide"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="xxx" class="basic-m" title="Y and X" label="Hide">
    <td>Hidden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="xxx2" class="basic-m" title="Y and X" label="Shown">
    <td>Shown</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```